# inserting elements from an array to a div's innerHTML using forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, innerhtml

I'm basically trying to first clear the form div by saying `form.innerHTML = ''`. Then when I try to insert one by one the elements from an array back to the form div using `forEach()` on the array, It just sets the `innerHTML` to the last element of an array.

Here's my JavaScript code **:**

```
 form.innerHTML = '';
 userCorrectAnswers.forEach(e => {
     let cA = e.innerHTML;
     form.innerHTML = cA;
 });
```

Need to know how can I add all the elements from that array to the `innerHTML` of the form.

Comment: change `form.innerHTML = cA;` to `form.innerHTML += cA;`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this via HTML text, build up all of the text then have the browser parse it all at once:

```
form.innerHTML = userCorrectAnswers.map(e => e.innerHTML).join("");
```

Note that that takes the **inner** HTML of the elements. If you wanted the elements themselves, not just their contents, that would be `outerHTML`:

```
form.innerHTML = userCorrectAnswers.map(e => e.outerHTML).join("");
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^
```

But if *that's* what you're doing, you might consider copying the elements instead via [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```
form.innerHTML = "";
for (const element of userCorrectAnswers) {
    form.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));
}
```

...so there's no need to first create an HTML string from the element, and then parse it again to put it in the form.

Comment: but can u please explain me how .join() is working??

Comment: @NeilsonProgrammer - MDN has excellent reference material for JavaScript, CSS, and the DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 0):

Since `userCorrectAnswers` is an Array of Elements — use [Element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)

```js
 form.append(...userCorrectAnswers);
```

```js
// DOM utility functions:
 
 const EL = (sel, par) => (par||document).querySelector(sel);
 const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
 
 // Task Example:
 
 const form = EL("#form");
 
 const userCorrectAnswers = [
   ELNew("div", {textContent:"Lorem"}),
   ELNew("div", {textContent:"Ipsum"}),
   ELNew("div", {textContent:"Dolor"}),
 ];
 
 form.append(...userCorrectAnswers);
```

```html
<div id="form"></div>
```

The above example using `.append()` used to *move* newly created or existing elements into another Element. Such will preserve any previously assigned Elements data or Events.

If you don't want to *move* your elements but ***clone*** them instead, use [Element.cloneNode(true)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) like:

```js
form.append(...userCorrectAnswers.map(el => el.cloneNode(true)));
```

---

To ***reduce*** an Array to String, use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
 form.innerHTML = userCorrectAnswers.reduce((str, el) => str += el.innerHTML, "");
```

```js
// DOM utility functions:
 
 const EL = (sel, par) => (par||document).querySelector(sel);
 const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
 
 // Task Example:
 
 const form = EL("#form");
 
 const userCorrectAnswers = [
   ELNew("div", {textContent:"Lorem"}),
   ELNew("div", {textContent:"Ipsum"}),
   ELNew("div", {textContent:"Dolor"}),
 ];

form.innerHTML = userCorrectAnswers.reduce((html, el) => html += el.outerHTML, "");
```

```html
<div id="form"></div>
```

The above example is not the best one since it just copies the HTML String, ignoring any previously Elements-assigned Event or data.

It makes use of [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) (instead of innerHTML) to *include* the selected target element tag as well as its contents. Use `innerHTML` if needed otherwise.